# running mysql with spring boot in docker: acess denied to database

Tags: mysql, spring, docker, access-denied

*aplication.properties*:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springapp
spring.datasource.username=www_data
spring.datasource.password=pass

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

*Dockerfile*:

```
FROM maven:3.8.5-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine
WORKDIR app
COPY src src
COPY pom.xml pom.xml
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -jar target/j1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

*docker-compose.yaml*:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  springapp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - j0-net
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/springapp
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
  mysqldb:
    image: "mysql"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - j0-net
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: springapp
      MYSQL_USER: www_data
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
networks:
  j0-net:
```

When running `docker compose up` for the first time. I am getting

```
...
#0 48.96 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
#0 48.96 
#0 48.96 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
...
```

after spring boots run. Running it second time I got

```
j1-springapp-1  | 
j1-springapp-1  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
j1-springapp-1  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
j1-springapp-1  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
j1-springapp-1  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
j1-springapp-1  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
j1-springapp-1  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
j1-springapp-1  |  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.0)
j1-springapp-1  | 
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:13.536Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.j1.J1Application             : Starting J1Application v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.3 with PID 1 (/app/target/j1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /app)
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:13.542Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.j1.J1Application             : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:15.049Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:15.173Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 105 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interface.
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:16.221Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:16.237Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:16.237Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.16]
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:16.338Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:16.341Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2619 ms
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:16.636Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:16.781Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.3.1.Final
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:16.866Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:17.357Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:17.412Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
j1-springapp-1  | 2023-11-26T20:42:18.985Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
j1-springapp-1  | 
j1-springapp-1  | java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'www_data'@'%' to database 'springapp'
j1-springapp-1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
j1-springapp-1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
j1-springapp-1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
...
```

Why? The user `www_data` with password `pass` is specified both in *application.properties* and *docker-compose.yaml*. So I assume the user is created and thus should have access to `springapp` database. So whats going on?

Projects source: https://github.com/shepherd123456/springapp

Comment: Wild guess: the database `springapp` does not exist. Please create the database, and give the user `www_data` access to tthis database.

Comment: @Turing85 well I cannot create database inside docker and creating data should be responsibility of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` specified in `application.properties`, and also cannot give permission to `www_data` since that is all happening in docker but thats why it is specified in `docker-compose.yaml` (i.e. `MYSQL_USER: www_data` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass`).

Comment: "*well I cannot create database inside docker*" - Of course you can. Please read the [`hub.docker.com` page of the mysql image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), especially the section "Initializing a fresh instance" --- "*creating data should be responsibility of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`*" - You are talking about the ddl, not the data, and yes, this can be responsibility of the app. But the RDBMS has to provide the database first.

Comment: @Turing85 I was following this https://medium.com/thefreshwrites/the-way-of-dockerize-a-spring-boot-and-mysql-application-with-docker-compose-de2fc03c6a42, there is not database initialization. Only `schema.sql` and `data.sql` which is for ddl, not creating database.

Comment: I have the same statement here `MYSQL_DATABASE: springapp` (of course changed database name to fit my test project, so also changed in `application.properties`)

Comment: Can you provide a reproducer, e.g. in form of a github repository?

Comment: @Turing85 sure, here you go: https://github.com/shepherd123456/springapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mysqldb` container takes a moment to start up. We have the 'depends_on`-section for` springapp`container in the`docker-compose.yaml`, but this only means that we start the` mysqldb`container before theh`springapp`container, not that the`mysql`service in the`mysqldb` container is actually ready.

To fix this, we have to do two things:

1. We need to know when the `mysql` service within the `mysqldb` container is ready
2. We need to delay the start of the `springapp` container until the `mysql` service is ready.

To achieve 1., we can provide a [health check (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck) for the `mysqldb` container. Luckily, since the container ships with `mysqladmin`, implementing the check means adding the following to the `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  ...
  mysqldb:
    ...
    healthcheck:
      test: [
        "CMD",
        "mysqladmin",
        "-h", "127.0.0.1",
        "--user=$$MYSQL_USER", # double quotes since the variable MYSQL_USER should be evaluated at container runtime
        "--password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD", # double quotes since the variable MYSQL_PASSWORD should be evaluated at container runtime
        "ping"
      ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
  ...
```

For 2., we can add [a condition to the `depends_on` (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#long-syntax-1) section of `springapp` in `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  springapp:
    ...
    depends_on:
      mysqldb:
        condition: service_healthy
    ...
```

Comment: services.mysqldb.environment.healthcheck must be a string, number, boolean or null

Comment: So it is not  parseable. Also it seems as wrong way to solve it (without even knowing IF it solves it), because then does every spring-mysql dockerization needs to do healthchecking? Would I need to healthcheck whenever I want to use these technologies dockerized? Does not seems right

Comment: What exactmy is "not parsable"? The `docker-compose.yml` works fine for me. --- When working with containers,, health checks are quite common. kubernetes, fof exampe. also relies on them to determin the readiness and liveness of pods.

Comment: It threw error because `healthcheck` was not last statement, now it works. And also is working the database. However, it is not populated, If you check the github source, I have `data.sql` to be run (also appropritate properties are set in application.properties), but is not executed. Or the whole question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77553806/populating-mysql-data-sql-in-docker-does-not-execute/77554425#77554425